# Is there a command-line equivalent to kdiff3 that allows selective merging?

Tags: command-line, kdiff3

kdiff3 is a GUI diff tool that allows you to create a diff of two/three files and selectively choose which lines make up the merged file. Is there a command-line equivalent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try

```
vimdiff file1 file2
```

Ex :

[image]

You can select lines (from command mode to visual mode) with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, copy with <kbd>yy</kbd>, paste with
<kbd>p</kbd> and switch into files with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ww</kbd>

See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html

Comment: To navigate: `]c` next change, `[c` previous change, `dp` 'diff put' to other buffer, `do` 'diff obtain' from other buffer

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [vimdiff](http://davitenio.wordpress.com/2008/09/11/merging-with-vimdiff/) (quick tutorial linked) is quite good at it. Being part of VIM, you will have to learn the key strokes you need to accept or refuse changes.