# Merging 3 XML files with kdiff3 (Command Line)

Tags: xml, matching, kdiff3

I need 3-way-merge of xml file, for this I am using kdiff3. The problem I am facing with kdiff3 is whenever there is the conflict in merging, kdiff3 is opening the kdiff3-GUI tool and ask to resolve a conflict. Kdiff3 is not saving the file with the conflict. 
How can I ask kdiff3 to save the file with conflict?

I am using the following command

```
kdiff3 --auto -m -o merged.xml base.xml  1.xml 2.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same can be achieved by git. Find below the command for this,

```
git merge-file -p mine.txt parent.txt yours.txt

-p Send results to standard output instead of overwriting <current-file>.
```